# Sending FormData to PHP file not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php

I have a XMLHttpRequest to send a `courseName` to php file on the server like this:

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
        }
    };
    const fd = new FormData();
    
    fd.append("courseName", 'Math');
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
```

PHP:

```
<?php

echo $_FILES['courseName']

?>
```

But nothing is returned, I'm confused please help... it should return Math, Doesn't it?

Comment: What do you see in the network panel? What do you see in the console? Does the PHP actually return anything?

Comment: `Server returned: `

Comment: Nothing more.... in console

Comment: So sounds like the PHP returns nothing. Unclear why you are using `$_FILES`

Comment: You're not adding a file to `fd` but regular form data. You should use `$_POST` instead of `$_FILES` for that.

Comment: @ rickdenhaan that's the point... thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The network doesn't show any data sent over.

[How to use FormData for AJAX file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Shows you how to send files using FormData ...

Best,
Smith